# When should I complete the square when I integrate?

Tags: integration

Ok, so I have tried to integrate this function:

$$\int \frac{1}{x^2+x+1}dx$$

I thought the answer was $$ln(x^2+x+1)+C$$

But my teacher said I should complete the square and use inverse tangens. I know how to do this. My question is how do I determine if I should complete the square or not when I integrate? Is it wrong to use the ln-function by the way?

Comment: The numerator is not the derivative of the denominator.

Comment: You need to integrate when you know a formal anti-derivative of what's inside. If not then you need to find other means: integration by parts, change of variable. Here you want a $\tan$ change so you need to complete the square to make it appear.

Comment: Try to rewrite the denominator $x^2+x+1=(x+...)^2+(...)^2$

Comment: Perhaps a more informative answer is that you complete the square to utilise the Pythagorean identities by a substitution.

Answer (score 1):

The answer you obtained is not correct becasue the derivative of the function you got is $\frac 1 {x^{2}+x+1} \frac d {dx} (x^{2}+x+1)$ by Chain Rule.

Write $x^{2}+x+1$ as $(x+\frac 1  2)^{2}+\frac 3 4 $ and make the substitution $y= \sqrt {\frac 4 3} (x+\frac  1 2)$ to evaluate the integral.

Answer (score 0):

**OP's both  approach and answer are not correct**

$\int \frac{dt}{a^2+t^2} dt=\frac{1}{a} \tan^{-1} (t/a)+C$
In order to solve your integral you have to find what is $t$ in your case. For this you have to make perfect square like $x^2+x+1=(x+1/2)^2+3/4$
then $$\int \frac{dx}{x^2+x+1} = \int \frac{dx}{(\sqrt{3}/2)^2+(x+1/2)^2}= \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \tan^{-1} \frac{(x+1/2)}{\sqrt{3}/{2}}+C$$